Is there any way of point singling in elliptic curve cryptography
Suppose a point is 2P (x, y)
Is there any way of getting point P?
P = (2P) /2
= (2P) ( 2^-1)
. = (2P) mod_invert(2)
Is it possible, practically?

Hi, this appears very similar to this question which was marked a duplicate (posted by an account with a similar name as yours). In the comments I posted some links to solutions to that question. Do those links answer your question? If not, can you edit your question to clarify where you got stuck with them?

And again, a simple method is using $P=((n+1)/2)(2P)$ where $n$ is an odd integer known for curves used in practice.
